# Read RSS XML Website

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

**Hi guys,**

I'm building an app for Android that reads RSS feeds from a website ..
I tried the RSS-ANDROID open source class that posted on GitHub but I can not figure out how to work with that.

I have no idea how to do this RSS-reading, there are any classes or codes that can help me?

thank!

Answer (score 0):

[Simple RSS Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) <- There's some examples of various ways to do this, because there are many.

Answer (score 0):

This library should do the trick. 
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It automatically handles all your RSS loading and parsing so you don't need to worry about it.